# How to repeat an action with different variables?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, if-statement, singleton

I'm not exactly sure on how to explain this, but I'm quite positive that there is a way to do this, but I haven't gotten it yet. Here's my example: I have a 10 variables (integer values) and with the value of the variable, a string gets set.

Here's an example with weather and the cloud covers to determine what the weather condition is:

```
        if (hour1cloud <= 5) {
            hour1weather = @"Clear";
        }
        if (5 < hour1cloud <= 25) {
            hour1weather = @"Mostly Clear";
        }
        if (25 < hour1cloud <= 50) {
            hour1weather = @"Partly Cloudy";
        }
        if (50 < hour1cloud <= 83) {
            hour1weather = @"Mostly Cloudy";
        }
        if (83 < hour1cloud <= 105) {
            hour1weather = @"Overcast";
        }
```

Let's say I have hour2cloud, hour3cloud, hour4cloud, etc which corrospond to hour2weather, hour3weather, and so on. Is there a way I can make a universal method where I just input the hour1cloud and retrieve the hour1weather?

Comment: stringWithFormat makes no sense in your code

Comment: @phix23 I had other testing other things as well which included conditions, etc. Took it off, thanks for notifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not write a method like this:

```
- (NSString*)weatherStringFromCloud:(int)cloud {
    NSString *weather;
    if (cloud <= 5) {
        weather = @"Clear";
    } else if (cloud <= 25) {
        weather = @"Mostly Clear";
    } else if (cloud <= 50) {
        weather = @"Partly Cloudy";
    } else if (cloud <= 83) {
        weather = @"Mostly Cloudy";
    } else if (cloud <= 105) {
        weather = @"Overcast";
    } else {
        weather = nil;
    }
    return weather;
}
```

And then call it with the various values:

```
hour1weather = [self weatherStringFromCloud:hour1cloud];
hour2weather = [self weatherStringFromCloud:hour2cloud];
hour3weather = [self weatherStringFromCloud:hour3cloud];
hour4weather = [self weatherStringFromCloud:hour4cloud];
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was thinking about in my question, I wasn't sure on what it was, but this brings my memory back!

Answer (score 2):

You could certainly do something like this:

```
static NSString *stringForCloudiness(int cloudiness) {
    static int const kCloudinesses[] = { 5, 25, 50, 83, 105 };
    static NSString *const kStrings[] = { @"Clear", @"Mostly Clear", @"Partly Cloudy", @"Mostly Cloudy", @"Overcast" };
    static int const kCount = sizeof kCloudinesses / sizeof *kCloudinesses;
    for (int i = 0; i < kCount; ++i) {
        if (cloudiness <= kCloudinesses[i]) {
            return kStrings[i];
        }
    }
    return @"A cloudiness level unparalleled in the history of recorded weather";
}
```

This is a little more complicated but ensures that you don't forget to keep the arrays in sync:

```
static NSString *stringForCloudiness(int cloudiness) {
    typedef struct {
        int cloudiness;
        __unsafe_unretained NSString *string;
    } CloudStringAssociation;

    static CloudStringAssociation const kAssociations[] = {
        { 5, @"Clear" },
        { 25, @"Mostly Clear" },
        { 50, @"Partly Cloudy" },
        { 83, @"Mostly Cloudy" },
        { 105, @"Overcast" },
        { INT_MAX, @"A cloudiness level unparalleled in the history of recorded weather" }
    };

    int i = 0;
    while (cloudiness > kAssociations[i].cloudiness) {
        ++i;
    }
    return kAssociations[i].string;
}
```

Comment: +1 for cloudiness level unparalleled. Thanks, this works great!